# How to approximate the time for running a ML code with parallel computing in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-caret

I am new to parallel computing and ML in R. So, I found it worrying when a programme could not complete after running over 15 minutes, as I have no idea how long should I expect a Machine learning programme on parallel computing would take or how to calculate the time the programme needs to run.

The following is a code on ML and parallel computing I tried which could not finish after 20 minutes. Could anyone suggest a way to figure out how long should I expect to wait for running 200000 rows of data with 14 columns on the following code? Or is there a problem with my code?

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(cores = 2)
set.seed(7)

fit.svmRadial <- train(gap~., data=trainingDataML, method="svmRadial", metric="RMSE",
    trControl=trainControl)
# summarize fit
print(fit.svmRadial)


library(parallel)
detectCores() # output: 4 cores
```

the Mac info is 
[image]

Comment: try running a series of analyses with (many) fewer columns and/or observations and figure out how the time scales with N and p ...

Comment: Thanks Ben! I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience parallelizing computation on Macbooks but I might be able to offer some advice as I commonly run ML algorithms that take hours or days to complete.

#### 1. 15 minutes is not that long

For 200,000 rows of data, 15 minutes is not long at all! Leave it to execute overnight or in the background while you do other work.

#### 2. Subset the input data and estimate the full run time

As Ben suggested I would subset the training data from 200,000 rows to say 2000 and track the time it takes to compute. I personally use this code to output the compute time.

```
sys.time = proc.time()
code...
print(proc.time() - sys.time);remove(sys.time)
```

Do this for several sizes of training data (at least 3 because it won't be linear!) and you can extrapolate to the full 200,000 rows. There is no hard and fast rule to how to select subset sizes so be cautious and start small - there is no point waiting an hour to run half the subset just to get a better prediction!

Comment: Thanks Vincent! This is helpful and it is a comfort to know that it is common to run ML codes for hours or overnight for dataset with size of 200000 rows. Then my immediate worry about running ML code for hours is that will it cause some damage to Mac as it becomes quite hot after 15 minute running. Maybe because of my lack of knowledge on computer, somehow I felt CPUs or my Mac may get them burnt if I let them running too long.

Comment: You *can* damage a computer by running it flat-out at 100% CPU/letting it get hot for a significant length of time. Laptops in particular are not built for such computations on a routine basis.  Make sure it's on a surface where it can dissipate heat (there are heat dissipation pads for laptops, possibly worth investing in), and very seriously consider finding another computational venue (e.g. cloud services such as Amazon Web Services)